# Internal Analytics API key?

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api, google-oauth

I know that the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) requires Open Authorization, which requires user confirmation.

Is there any alternative if I just need it for my own internal usage? Can I skip the confirmation part?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount).   A service account will allow you to access your own Google Analytics data with out requiring authentication.

Once you have created a service account in the [Google Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) you can then take the service account email address and add it as a user at the **ACCOUNT** level like you would any other user.

Then you will be able to use the service account to authenticate to the [Google analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference).